# DOS Batch script return code not being returned to caller

Tags: batch-file, cmd, error-handling, errorlevel

We have a file1.cmd calling file2.cmd calling file3.cmd.

file3.cmd returns a failure as: exit /b 1

But in file2.cmd we seem to "lose" this failure code.  The %ERRORLEVEL% variable is being listed as 0 instead of 1.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have `set errorlevel=0` in your code? Is the call and the test inside parenthesis an not using delayed expansion? Why do you not use `if errorlevel 1` ?

Comment: Don't have set errorlevel=0...

Comment: if errorlevel 1 seems to work..  nice!   Go ahead and enter an answer and I will accept it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usual problems that can be found:

**Setting the errorlevel variable to a value**

```
set errorlevel=0
echo test | find "x" > nul 2>nul
echo %errorlevel%
```

Here the errorlevel will be set (the `find` operation has failed) but the value echoed to console will be 0. `errorlevel` is a dynamic variable and setting a value to it blocks the access to the dynamic value. `errorlevel` value should not be set with the `set` command.

If it is necessary to set errorlevel you can

- When leaving the running batch: `exit n` or `exit /b n`
- Inside the running batch, without leaving it: `cmd /c exit n`

in both cases with `n` the numeric value to set in the errorlevel

To clear the errorlevel you can use: `ver>nul`

**Variable expansion**

```
if 1==1 (
    echo test | find "x" > nul 2>nul
    if %errorlevel%==1 echo failed
)
```

When the batch parser reaches a line or a block of lines (lines enclosed in parenthesis), it replaces all the read operations on variables with the value inside the variable **before** execute the line/block. So, if a variable changes its value inside the line/block, the new value can no be retrieved from inside the same line/block. The read operation does not exist, it was replaced with the initial value.

Delayed expansion can be enabled, allowing to change (where needed) the syntax from `%var%` to `!var!`, indicating to the parser that the read operation must be delayed until the command executes

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
if 1==1 (
    echo test | find "x" > nul 2>nul
    if !errorlevel!==1 echo failed
)
```

**But** for any of the two previous cases, there is an alternative. The batch language includes a construct to test for errorlevel that is not affected by assigned values or variable expansion

```
if errorlevel n .....
```

This construct will be evaluated to true for any errorlevel greater or equal to `n`. For this reason, when using this construct and testing for different error levels, it is necessary to test for `errorlevel` from greater to lower values

```
if errorlevel 3 (
    ....
) else if errorlevel 2 (
    ....
) else if errorlevel 1 ( 
    ....
) else (
  ....
)
```

In the cases where the only check is if errorlevel is set or not, this construct can be abreviated using conditional execution

```
command && ( .... ) || ( .... )
```

where the commands after the `&&` are executed when the errorlevel is not set, and the commands after `||` are executed when the errorlevel is set